# How to pass data to the caller page?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces JSF library and the following code to open a page in the popup dialog:

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false" onclick="PopupMultiFileSelect('multi_file_select.faces', 'Select files','500','300'); return false;">
    <h:graphicImage style="border: none" value="./img/add.jpg"/> 
</p:commandLink>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
function PopupMultiFileSelect(pageURL, title, w, h) 
{
var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
var childWin = window.open (pageURL, '_blank', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);

if ( childWin.opener==null ) 
    childWin.opener = self;

return childWin;
}
```

What I do in the popup page is just select some filenames and place the names inside a string List, like so:

```
    List<String> fileNames;
```

How would I pass the List down to the caller page?

Comment: Why all that unnecessary effort of homebrewing HTML/JS? Why not just using the ready-to-use [`<p:dialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf)?

Comment: Is that list inside a managed bean that the caller page has access to? If so just refresh the page (or the relevant part) when closing the popup and read the data from the list.

Comment: @BalusC: It seamed to me that `<p:dialog>` is just for simple stuff; I need to load a completely new html page inside this dialog, a page with it's own backing bean, etc. Is `<p:dialog>` the way to go in this case too?

Comment: Redesign that page than. It's perfectly fine for the page to have its own backing bean. Just inject it in the bean of the parent page.

Comment: @BalusC: You mean to put whole complicated html page inside `<p:dialog>` tags?

Comment: No, just the piece in the `<body>`. Put `<ui:composition>` around the content of `<body>` then you can just use `<ui:include>`.

Comment: Homebrewing html&js? :-)

Comment: @BalusC: Tried `<p:dialog>` via `<ui:include>` and it (nearly) works: different problem now - component in the caller page gets updated before `actionListener()` has finished his job in the popup. Please, try to help here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317922/ajax-component-updates-before-actionlistener-called)

Comment: @BalusC Do I really put `<ui:composition>` around `<body>` tag? Which `<h:form id="formPageAId">` tag is than used inside dialog? Or should I put `<ui:composition>` after `<h:form>` tag?

Comment: Tried everything but no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use f:param to pass information to another page.
See this example :

```
<f:param name="listnames" value="#{bean.fileNames}" />
```

Comment: This is not applicable in this particular use case.

Comment: @java_developer: Thanks. I still don't understand how this would work. Could you give a bit more pseudo code to illustrate?

Comment: Let's say I have page A which prints file names, and page B which is popped up from page A where I select those filenames. How would I pass them down from page B to page A?