# Ajax component updates before actionListener called?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, actionlistener

I am using PrimeFaces `<p:dialog>` to launch a popup html page and `<p:commandButton>` to close it:

This is what I do when Ok button is pressed:

```
<p:commandButton id="submitButton" 
    value="OK" 
    actionListener="#{MultiFileSelectMgmtBean.actionOk}" 
    update=":formID:fileTreeID" 
    oncomplete="dlg1.hide();"/>
```

Problem is that `fileTreeID` is updated before action listener is done. 
How do I force `actionOk()` to be called first, and then `fileTreeID` to be updated?

**Edit**:

The problem is that popup page B (`BackingBeanB`) needs to calculate and save some values that parent page A loads and uses in its `BackingBeanA::BackingBeanA`constructor. What happens is that parent page A is constructed *before* child page B calls its `BackingBeanB::actionOk()`. The component that needs to be updated `fileTreeID` is in page A, and depends on the values calculated in page A constructor, so it gets updated with old values, and not with new ones to be calculated in `BackingBeanB::actionOk()`.

Comment: This is not true. Either you're misinterpreting the problem, or the cause is somewhere else.

Comment: @BalusC: I've edited the question, please check if it's now clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Your beans are apparently in the request scope. Put the beans in the view scope instead.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BeanA {}
```

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BeanB {}
```

This way the beans will live as long as you're interacting with the same view and not be reconstructed on every single HTTP request.

The `update` is definitely not performed *before* the action is invoked. Possible construction of the backing beans is not necessarily performed during render response only. It can happen during restore view phase already.

Comment: How do you recommed to pass the values from child "page" B to parent A? What I did so far was to save it in `Map<String,Object>  sessionVars = FacesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();` and then `sessionVars.put` in page B and `sessionVars.get` in page A.